# How can I use the Magento UI library to display a link as a button?

Tags: css, uicomponent, magento2.4

I'm migrating an old module to Magento 2.4 and I would like to use the native classes from the Magento UI library to replace my Bootstrap classes.

What classes should I use to make my links look like buttons? I've read the Magento UI doc (`lib/web/css/docs`) but I can't figure out which class names I should be using. The original bootstrap style link is here:

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank"class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-recrutement btn-candidature">Text</a>
```

I've just found: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/web/css/source/lib/_buttons.less but so far, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these two classes in your anchor tag

```
  <a href="#" class="action primary">Text</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you mind explaining where you found which classes to apply?

Comment: Simply inspect any button in magento website and see what classes are applied to that button, you can find it easily